# JavaScript countdown until date

Tags: javascript, date, timer, countdown

So I'm trying to build a very minimalistic countdown timer until a specific date (2015 July 31, 18:00:00 GMT) including total MS until the date, as well as a D:H:M:S:MS until the date.

What I got so far is at this codepen: 
http://codepen.io/svbeon/pen/MwBJNJ
With this JS:

```
setInterval(times, 1);
function times() {
today = new Date();
July = new Date(Date.UTC(2015,06,31,18,0,0,0));
diffMs = ((July - today) - today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); // milliseconds between now & July 31 
diffDays = (July.getDate() - today.getDate()); // days
diffHrs = (24 + ((July.getHours() - today.getHours()) + (today.getTimezoneOffset() / 60))); // hours
diffMins = (60 + (July.getMinutes() - today.getMinutes())); // minutes
diffSecs = (60 + (July.getSeconds() - today.getSeconds())); // seconds
diffMis = (1000 + (July.getMilliseconds() - today.getMilliseconds())); //milliseconds


if (diffMs <= 0) {
    diffMs = 0;
    diffDays = 0;
    diffHrs = 0;
    diffMins = 0;
    diffSecs = 0;
    diffMis = 0;
    }

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = diffMs + " miliseconds";
document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = diffDays + " days " + diffHrs + " Hours " + diffMins + " Minutes " + diffSecs + " seconds " + diffMis + " milliseconds";
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "until " + July;
}
```

The problems I get here is that it can echo something like `14 days 24 hours 60 minutes 60 seconds 1000 milliseconds` when it in fact should be `14 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds 0 milliseconds` as well as after 18:00 UTC it still says `14 days` instead of `13 days` until midnight.

I got no real idea of how to simply fix these problems
Adding one less for example:

```
diffSecs = (59 + (July.getSeconds() - today.getSeconds())); // seconds
```

Will result in the timer showing 0 instead of 60, but will as well make the timer go 1 second wrong (minute or hour if you have it on their part)

So if you happen to have any idea how to fix this and help a not so skilled developer iIwould be really happy!!

Comment: Did I mention it must be accessible with the same output in all timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs), as it makes date/time manipulation much simpler and will probably help you solve this problem also.

For instance to get a difference between two dates in milliseconds:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

Then create a `duration` from the result of the difference in milliseconds and use `milliseconds()`, `seconds()`, etc functions to display `duration` in different units:

```
moment.duration(1500).milliseconds(); // 500
moment.duration(1500).seconds(); // 1
```

Partial solution: https://jsfiddle.net/krlkv/xvstvfdb/3/

Comment: I'll look into it for further projects, sure looks cool. But as this is something I only need quickly I don't have time to learn a new Framework...

Comment: It's not a framework, it a small and very convenient de-facto standard library for date/time manipulation in JS.  You might actually save yourself time grasping and using it instead of using vanilla JS.

Comment: For instance to get a difference between two dates in milliseconds: `var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]); var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]); a.diff(b) // 86400000`

Comment: It still doesn't display right day count or time count... It's still wrong 1 number...

Comment: do you use `durations` and their display in miliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc?  this is exactly what you need as far as i understand.  and it takes way less amount of code.

Comment: And with the diff function it doesn't even get the correct amount of milliseconds between the dates

Comment: really?  for example?

Comment: @kyrklkov well compare the codepen in the post to http://codepen.io/svbeon/pen/JdBOGb

Comment: But if you got the time, could you make a timer doing about what my timer in original post does using moment.js and I can see and learn how to do for further reference? Shouldn't take more than 5 Mins... A codepen or something... Because I'm really in a hurry...

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough! Enormous thanks to you, hopefully this will be used over and over! Kudos to you!

Comment: Oh wait... I Need to get time1 in UTC and not my local Timezone

Comment: use Moments Timezone to create now and future dates in UTC http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

Just use mod:

`day = day%24;
secs = secs%60;`

and etc.

Comment: Well sadly it doesn't solve anything really, it just return (for secs) -22 and then -23...